# Join two dataframes based on common value in column (which is array)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join

I have one dataframe - `df_similar_strings`, which looks like this:

```
|---------------------|
|     string_values   |
|---------------------|
|  ['catish', 'cat']  |
|---------------------|
|  ['doggo', 'dogy']  |
|---------------------|
```

and the other one - `df_source`:

```
|-----------------------------|------------------|
|             values          |     key_value    |
|-----------------------------|------------------|
|  ['catish', 'cat', 'cat-']  |        cat       |
|-----------------------------|------------------|
|  ['doggo', 'dogy', 'dog']   |        dog       |
|-----------------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to join those data frames based on the column `string_values` and `values` so that there is at least one value matching.
I have no idea how to do this since the columns are nested as arrays.

Comment: Can you describe in more details what should the output be? You want to join the dataframes if all values match (for each couple of cells) or only if one of them?

Comment: @OmriKaduri I've updated the question - I want at least one value to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by first doing a cartesian-product between your two dataframes and then dropping from that dataframe all rows which doesn't have any shared value.

For simplicity, I assume the columns on both datasets have the same name ("values"). Also, I assume the lists doesn't have repeated values (all values appear once).

```py
from collections import Counter

def find_duplicates(arr):
    return [item for item,count in Counter(arr).items() if count==2]

df1['key']=1
df2['key']=1
cartes_prod_df = df1.merge(df2,on=['key'],how='outer').drop(columns=['key'])
duplicate_values = (cartes_prod_df.values_x + cartes_prod_df.values_y).apply(find_duplicates)

merged_df = cartes_prod_df[duplicate_values.apply(lambda x: len(x)>0)]
```

I've used a little trick in order to do the cartesian product (Adding the `key` column), and then the `duplicate_values` found from the joint array (using the `+` operator) are the values which appeared twice in the joint array.

**UPDATE**

In order to supply a full example, here's an example of `df1` and `df2`:

```py
d1 = {'values': [['A','B'],['B','C'],['D']],'otherkey':[1,2,3]}

d2 = {'values': [['A'],['B'],['A','C'],['D']],'otherkey':[4,5,3,6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Now, `merged_df` would give the output:
[image]

Comment: doesn't it seem to be problematic to `cartes_prod_df.values_x + cartes_prod_df.values_y` where columns `values_x` and `values_y` are arrays in dataframes? I am getting: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

Comment: No, `+` operator between lists in python is a simple way to join them into one list. It works on pandas columns too (if both columns contain lists)

Comment: All good, I realized that in one of the column the type was string so that's why `+` didn't work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Hey you just need to type cast your list to tuple. And then try merging. Since list is unhashable hence merge operation can't be applied. Try this

```
df_source.values = df_source["values"].apply(lambda x: tuple(x))
```

Similarly with the other df and try merging using pd merge.

Comment: Important to mention that this solution will merge only rows with exactly same tuple (and not tuples which are different but have some intersection)

Comment: @OmriKaduri yeah, I would need something else since I want at least one value to match

Comment: That's right. It will only match for exact same tuple. This is quite interesting problem to solve.

Comment: @UjjwalAgrawal, hey Ujjwal, thanks for sharing nice code. I have edited your 2 posts as per forum's rules our codes should be wrapped in CODE TAGS, I have done this here, cheers and keep up the good answers coming cheers :)